# How to make Django OneToOne relation unique across models

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, one-to-one

I have User model, and 2 profile models (ProfileA, ProfileB). Profile models are OneToOne to User, but how to make User to be unique in both Profile models?

```
class User():
    name = CharField()
    

class ProfileA():
    user = OneToOneField(User)


class ProfileB():
    user = OneToOneField(User)
    
    
user = User.objects.create(name='abc')
profileA = ProfileA.objects.create(user=user)
profileB = ProfileB.objects.create(user=user)
```

The problem is that I'm allowed to create profileA and profileB with the same user object, but I want to disallow.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have this solution:

```
class ProfileA():
    user = OneToOneField(User)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if ProfileB.objects.filter(user=self.user).exists():
            raise ValueError
        super(ProfileA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ProfileB():
    user = OneToOneField(User)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if ProfileA.objects.filter(user=self.user).exists():
            raise ValueError
        super(ProfileB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```